# How to fix Shop is invalid error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, e-commerce

I am trying to create a product for a shop, and i am trying to add that shopID to that particular product, but each time i try sending the post request, I keep getting ShopID is invalid error.

Here are my code...

Model for Shop..

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const shopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your shop name!"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your shop email address"],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your password"],
    minLength: [6, "Password should be greater than 6 characters"],
    select: false,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: "Seller",
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  zipCode: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordTime: Date,
});

// Hash password
shopSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
});

// jwt token
shopSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES,
  });
};

// comapre password
shopSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("Shop", shopSchema);
```

Shop Controller

```
router.post("/create-shop", upload.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const sellerEmail = await Shop.findOne({ email });

    if (sellerEmail) {
      const filename = req.file.filename;
      const filePath = `uploads/${filename}`;
      fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).json({ message: "Error deleting file" });
        }
      });
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Shop already exists", 400));
    }

    const filename = req.file.filename;
    const fileUrl = path.join(filename);

    const seller = {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: email,
      password: req.body.password,
      avatar: fileUrl,
      address: req.body.address,
      phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      zipCode: req.body.zipCode,
    };

    const activationToken = createActivationToken(seller);

    const activationUrl = `http://localhost:3000/seller/activation/${activationToken}`;

    try {
      await sendMail({
        email: seller.email,
        subject: "Activate your Shop Account",
        message: `Hello ${seller.name}, please click on the link to activate your shop: ${activationUrl}`,
      });
      res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: `please check your email:- ${seller.email} to activate your shop!`,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400));
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Products Model..

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your product name!"],
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your product description!"],
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your product category!"],
  },
  tags: {
    type: String,
  },
  originalPrice: {
    type: Number,
  },
  discountPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "Please enter your product price!"],
  },
  stock: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "Please enter your product stock!"],
  },
  images: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  shopId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  shop: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  sold_out: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

Products Controller

```
    const express = require("express");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middleware/catchAsyncErrors");
const router = express.Router();
const Product = require("../model/product");

const Shop = require("../model/shop");

const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/ErrorHandler");
const { upload } = require("../multer");

// create product

    router.post(
      "/create-product",
      upload.array("images"),
      catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          const shopId = req.body.shopId;
          const shop = await Shop.findById(shopId);
    
          console.log(shop);
          if (!shop) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Shop Id is invalid!", 400));
          } else {
            const files = req.files;
            const imageUrls = files.map((file) => `${file.filename}`);
            const productData = req.body;
            productData.images = imageUrls;
            productData.shop = shop;
    
            const product = await Product.create(productData);
    
            res.status(201).json({
              success: true,
              product,
            });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          return next(new ErrorHandler(error, 400));
        }
      })
    );
    module.exports = router;
```

Products Action Redux

```
    import axios from "axios";
import { server } from "../../server";

// create product
export const createProduct = (newForm) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "productCreateRequest",
    });

    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `${server}/product/create-product`,
      newForm,
      config
    );
    dispatch({
      type: "productCreateSuccess",
      payload: data.product,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: "productCreateFail",
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Form for Products creation

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlinePlusCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { createProduct } from "../../redux/actions/product";
import { categoriesData } from "../../static/data";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const CreateProduct = () => {
  const { seller } = useSelector((state) => state.seller);
  const { success, error } = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState("");
  const [originalPrice, setOriginalPrice] = useState();
  const [discountPrice, setDiscountPrice] = useState();
  const [stock, setStock] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      toast.error(error);
    }
    if (success) {
      toast.success("Product created successfully!");
      navigate("/dashboard");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, success]);

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let files = Array.from(e.target.files);
    setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, ...files]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newForm = new FormData();

    images.forEach((image) => {
      newForm.append("images", image);
    });
    newForm.append("name", name);
    newForm.append("description", description);
    newForm.append("category", category);
    newForm.append("tags", tags);
    newForm.append("originalPrice", originalPrice);
    newForm.append("discountPrice", discountPrice);
    newForm.append("stock", stock);
    newForm.append("shopId", seller._id);
    dispatch(
      createProduct({
        newForm,
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-[90%] 800px:w-[50%] bg-white  shadow h-[80vh] rounded-[4px] p-3 overflow-y-scroll">
      <h5 className="text-[30px] font-Poppins text-center">Create Product</h5>
      {/* create product form */}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">
            Name <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            className="mt-2 appearance-none block w-full px-3 h-[35px] border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter your product name..."
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">
            Description <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
          </label>
          <textarea
            cols="30"
            required
            rows="8"
            type="text"
            name="description"
            value={description}
            className="mt-2 appearance-none block w-full pt-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter your product description..."
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">
            Category <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
          </label>
          <select
            className="w-full mt-2 border h-[35px] rounded-[5px]"
            value={category}
            onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="Choose a category">Choose a category</option>
            {categoriesData &&
              categoriesData.map((i) => (
                <option value={i.title} key={i.title}>
                  {i.title}
                </option>
              ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">Tags</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="tags"
            value={tags}
            className="mt-2 appearance-none block w-full px-3 h-[35px] border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            onChange={(e) => setTags(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter your product tags..."
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">Original Price</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="price"
            value={originalPrice}
            className="mt-2 appearance-none block w-full px-3 h-[35px] border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            onChange={(e) => setOriginalPrice(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter your product price..."
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">
            Price (With Discount) <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="price"
            value={discountPrice}
            className="mt-2 appearance-none block w-full px-3 h-[35px] border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            onChange={(e) => setDiscountPrice(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter your product price with discount..."
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">
            Product Stock <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="price"
            value={stock}
            className="mt-2 appearance-none block w-full px-3 h-[35px] border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            onChange={(e) => setStock(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter your product stock..."
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label className="pb-2">
            Upload Images <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            name=""
            id="upload"
            className="hidden"
            multiple
            onChange={handleImageChange}
          />
          <div className="w-full flex items-center flex-wrap">
            <label htmlFor="upload">
              <AiOutlinePlusCircle size={30} className="mt-3" color="#555" />
            </label>
            {images &&
              images.map((i) => (
                <img
                  src={URL.createObjectURL(i)}
                  key={i}
                  alt=""
                  className="h-[120px] w-[120px] object-cover m-2"
                />
              ))}
          </div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Create"
              className="mt-2 cursor-pointer appearance-none text-center block w-full px-3 h-[35px] border border-gray-300 rounded-[3px] placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateProduct;
```

Comment: Can you attach the exact error message, and partial stack trace?